# Internet explorer automation - copy information off webpage

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-11

Basically I'm just looking for a way to copy data from a text box using Powershell which I'm relatively new at. I can navigate to the webpage using internet explorer and input data into text boxes; yet I haven't seen anyone who has retrieved data using Powershell. Note I'm not using an API or desiring to copy the entire page, just a tiny very predictable integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to give specific pointers without knowing what page you are looking at, but the general idea is as follows:

Get the entire YouTube.com page and save it as an object

```
$Object = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://youtube.com"
```

Select all "Forms" on the page and view their contents.  Note that since a button can be considered a field this may also appear as a result.

```
$Object.Forms.Fields
```

Output:

```
Key                  Value
---                  -----
action_logout        1
masthead-search-term
```

Decent primer:http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/create-web-scraping-tool-in-powershell,2-1091.html